# How can I know the Hyper-V VM's last poweroff time

Tags: windows, wmi, hyper-v

I am looking for a way to know when is the last time Hyper-V VM powered off.

What I would like to do is, check for the storace space used by Hyper-V VMs that has not been powered on for a long time.

I checked for other questions and found that with wmi, Win32_OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime property I can recognize the last boot time for powered on windows os, but it is not possible to connect to powerred off VMs so this is not good. 
I also checked for Hyper-V wmi properties, but could not find a way to do that.

If you have any good idea, please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the [Msvm_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object for the VM, and inspect the TimeOfLastStateChange field.  Use the EnabledState field to judge whether the VM is on or off.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, TimeOfLastStateChange seems not solving this problem, as it shows last-boot-time for poweredOn vms, and something like 'Recent time' for poweredOff vms. I would like to find a way to know the "last poweredOff time" for powered off vms. Any help is appliciated.